# Using Backbone and Trying To Populate My Collection With Data From Parse.com

Tags: backbone.js, collections, parse-platform

Very new to Backbone here. I am trying to recreate the ToDo example without copying and pasting code from the tutorials I've encountered. I am also using Parse.com as my back-end. I am stuck on trying to populate my collection with todo items using a Backbone View. Here is my View ...

```
app.ItemsView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "section",

    initialize: function() {
        app.items = new app.ItemCollection;
        app.items.query = new Parse.Query(app.Item);
        app.items.fetch();

        console.log(app.items.models.length);

        var itemsInJSON = [];

        app.items.models.forEach(function(item){
            console.log("Item being pushed is " + item);
            itemsInJSON.push(item.toJSON());
        });

        this.render(app.items);
    },

    render: function(items) {
        items.each(this.addItem, this);
        return this;
        // $("#bucketList").html(itemsView.render().el);
    },

    addItem: function(item) {
        var itemView = new app.ItemView ({model: item});
        this.$el.append(itemView.render().el)
    }

});
```

I have checked my application on Parse.com and I can see I have 2 items saved in my database. I know there is a problem because when I call `console.log(app.items.models.length);` in initialize, I get a length of 0. But when I type `app.items.models.length`directly in the Chrome Dev Tools console after the page has loaded, I get a length of 2.

Why is my initialize not fetching the items to populate my collection?

Comment: `fetch` is asynchronous - it hasn't completed before the `console.log(..)` statement but has when you check in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Since `fetch` actually does an AJAX request it's asynchronous and you have to deal with that fact. It returns a [jqXHR](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object as stated in the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) so your code should do something like this

```
app.items.fetch().then(function() {
  console.log(app.items.models.length);
  ...
  this.render();
}.bind(this));
```

That makes sure the code you have which relies on the result of the AJAX requests only gets executed after that request has completed.

Note that I use `.bind(this)` to make sure that within the callback for the jqXHR promise I can access the view as `this`. This only works for IE9+ (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)) and if you need to support IE8 or lower use underscore's [_.bind](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) instead.

Comment: Ahhh ok. Thanks for pointing out that `fetch()` is an AJAX request. Knowing this now, I decided to use a callback function via a success option just like I would for an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to not use Jquery in promise in this case.
Backbone use events to manage/help in this case.

The 1st thing that you should to do, is move the model/collection logic (fetch, set, get and etc) to inside the model/collection

Then you could have something like this inside your view:

```
this.lintenTo(app.items, "sync", this.render);
```

This is the backbone way to deal with these situations.

**But why not use Promises?**

When you perform fetch() inside your view, you’re already breaking the SRP, because if for some reason in the future, you need to change how the fetch will be called, you gonna need to touch the view file, but remember that fetch is a model/collection function, and in my opinion it means that the view is having more than one reason to change. Also when you perform fetch() inside the view and use promises, you need to use bind(this) to keep the scope, in my opinion you could avoid it just passing this code to the model/collection and just listen for events in view.
And the same for any model/collection function(fetch, save,destroy, set, get ….)

Comment: Should I move the collection logic into the initialize option within my collection constructor, @rcarvalho?

Comment: Not all the logic, but in this case you just have the fetch logic. I would create a function called 'fetchContent' inside the collection(or)model and then perform the fetch();

Comment: I think you should expand on why using promises breaks SRP, and I'd love to hear more about how it makes writing unit tests more complicated.

Comment: Thank you. I see where you're coming from but I don't necessarily agree. There are times when something happening in the view triggers a need for a server request and in those cases I think it's fine for the view to trigger a fetch. I think a blanket statement against that is wrong but I'll agree that in the OPs usecase it's good advice. I've never had any problems writing tests for code that uses promises though ;)